# memcache can't connect, localhost don't work

Tags: php, memcached

I'm working in a remote project and I can see in the php info that memcache is installed.
But this is not working:

```
# Connect to memcache:
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Can't connect");
```

I don't have access to the control panel where my project is, but I have it in zend studio, and I also can see php info.

[image]

Basically I would like to know what I have to put in the place of 'localhost', any help would be apreciated.

Comment: is memcached installed on the server?.... just because php has memcached module doesn't mean the memcache server is also installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks and sounds like memcached is not installed on the server.  It could also be that it is not running even if it is installed.  Install or turn it on somehow.  You could also try putting 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but unlikely to make a difference... good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I can install it, must talk with my CTO. Thanks anyway!